# Wordpress getting the title of current page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have begun writing a theme for wordpress. A question:

How should I assign each page that I make, a title specific to that page (which is set in the admin panel by the admin when the page was created).

Wordpress has a set of arbitary pages. For instance:

```
page.php
category.php
single.php
```

How should I fetch the title then? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the HTML `<title>` you should use [`wp_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) in `header.php`

```
<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

If you're after a title to go into a `<h1>` (etc), then [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) is the tag which you need. An minimal page.php file would be something like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()):
  the_post(); ?>
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<?php wp_title(); ?>` you can get the title of the current page that you want. Beside this do take a reference to [WordPress.org documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) on title.